# Drop down menu suddenly stopped working

Tags: javascript, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm using Wordpress (theme: future) built on bootstrap. The theme is responsive and on mobile view the menu transforms to a dropdown menu. Even in the desktop version I have a dropdown menu on one of the menu options, but suddenly both these dropdown menus has stopped working.

I haven't done any changes to the source code except from the css files. In the console there are two javascript errors, though I'm not sure if they are connected to this problem:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'         bootstrap.min.js?ver=3.0.3:9
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'tooltip'    custom.js?ver=1.0:62
```

When I hover the drop down menu it links to "#" but I suppose that's correct? Otherwise I  don't have a clue where to start with this problem and will of course include code if you just tell me which one.

EDIT: Here is the site, http://www.henrikpetersson.se/lararummet/

Comment: can we see the relevant code?

Comment: If you don't know what code to post can you post the link to the site?

Comment: @MaxMeijer: http://www.henrikpetersson.se/lararummet/

Comment: need a login to see http://www.henrikpetersson.se/lararummet/ but my guess is that jquery isn't loading. type `window.jQuery` into the js console in your browser. it should return `function()` or `object{}`. If it returns, `undefined` start looking for why jquery isn't loading.

Comment: The login page doesnt show any error in the console (chrome)

Comment: @Will: jQuery is loading fine. The site should be open now if you wanna have a look.

Comment: @MaxMeijer: I know and that's the strange part. The code worked fine before but suddenly stopped working and no error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your site is using [jQuery 1.4](http://www.henrikpetersson.se/lararummet/wp-content/plugins/sponsors-carousel/jquery-1.4.2.min.js?ver=1.4.2) but the [on() method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) wasn't added until jQuery 1.7. Bootstrap is trying to use it and causing the error.

It's possible the carousel plugin you're using is loading this old version of jQuery and preventing WordPress from loading a newer one. See the source of the jquery 1.4 link above (from the plugin's directory). Try disabling that plugin and see if your menu works. WordPress ships with a more modern version of jQuery.

**Edit**
Yup. That plugin was last updated in 2012 and it loads jQuery in the worst possible way.

```
function sponsors_carousel_enqueue_scripts() {
    if ( function_exists('plugin_url') )
        $plugin_url = plugin_url();
    else
        $plugin_url = get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-content/plugins/' . plugin_basename(dirname(__FILE__));

    // jquery
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', ($plugin_url  . '/jquery-1.4.2.min.js'), false, '1.4.2');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

Source: http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/sponsors-carousel/trunk/sponsors-carousel.php

The plugin is essentially saying

1. Unregister whatever version of jQuery WP wants to load
2. Make a new script called jQuery with my ancient version (because I'm always right)
3. Load my awesome version.

Terrible.

**Options**

1. Find another carousel plugin
2. Edit this plugin and remove all three of those lines (should be fine)
3. (if 2. doesn't work...) Edit this plugin and point it at a more modern version of jQuery

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer! The carousel plugin was causing this problem and deactivating it the problem was solved.